# abstract activity causes findViewById() not to work

Tags: java, android

I have an abstract `Activity` as most of my activities share the same menu:

```
public abstract class ActivityBase extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menubar, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      //...

      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      //...
    }
}
```

Now, when I use that class (inherit from it), the `findViewById()` method doesn't work anymore. Doesn't matter if I even inherit from it in that particular class, once it is somewhere in the inheritance tree, it doesn't work anymore. For example:

```
public class SomeOther extends ActivityBase {
}

public class Home extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button); // fails, NullPointerException
}
```

What could be the cause of this, and even more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: how does it fail? the button is null or what? castexception? paste the logcat

Comment: is button in the same main.xml file?

Comment: yes. It worked before I introduced the `ActivityBase` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` was caused someplace else and just manifested with that method. If you derive from `Application` and try to call `getSharedPreferences`, it fails, but you can't pinpoint it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this work perfect (try this)...

```
public abstract class ActivityBase extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  //..
  return true;
 }
}
```

and

```
public class MyActActivity extends ActivityBase {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.e("HI", "Hello");
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Settings_phoneNumbersT1);
    Log.e("HI", tv.toString());
}
}
```

and `main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Settings_phoneNumbersT1"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" android:text="Hellofffff"/>


 </LinearLayout>
```

So, I don't think it is problem of Abstract ActivityBase class.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that in my sample. I called `setContentView(...)` of course.

Comment: yep, it works for me as well now. The cause was somewhere else and just manifested there.

Comment: I can only accept my own answer in two days. While I appreciate your help, it wasn't really the solution. Upvoted though for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
Button b = (Button)Home.this.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

its to make sure that your present class's findviewById is called and not the super class's..